# How to not escape chars in JSTL using c:out

Tags: java, javascript, jstl

i'm using JSTL `<c:out>` in my project to support javascript code, i have a string that comes from the servlet like this `"2\'000;11\'222;10\'333"` with javascript i'd like to split it to obtain separated values like `2'000;11'222;10'333`....but when i use the `<c:out>` tag this `"\'"` becames `"\&#039;"` messing up the split function....

is there a way to tell JSTL not escape chars ?

```
stringaCompleta += 'Gennaio;<c:out value="${valori.value}" />';
```

Comment: Please show the relevant snippet of your JSP code.

Comment: set attribute xmlOut="true" or xml="true" something like this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply don't use the `c:out` tag at all:

```
stringaCompleta += 'Gennaio;${valori.value}';
```

Or use it with `escapeXml` set to false (but it's needlessly complex):

```
stringaCompleta += 'Gennaio;<c:out value="${valori.value}" escapeXml="false" />';
```

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) would have told you.